# float right and css transform does not work correct together

Tags: html, css

I have two div in my container,to keep these two div beside each other i use inline-flex display for my container.inside of  one of my child div(div with "wrapper" class) I want to show some div and keep them inline,for this reason i use float for my card div and every thing is OK,also i use CSS transform translate for hovering on card div.The problem is when I hover on card div,it has to move up,but first it moves to right a little the it goes up,and all of other card div that come after this div( which I hover on it) will move to right for a second,and I have this problem just in google chrome version 59.I think they move to right because I use float to right.if I don't use relative position for container div,other div won't move to right when i hover on one div,but still that specific div will move to right then up.
here is my code:

```
<div class="all-results">
  <div class="filter">...</div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="card">..</div>
    <div class="card">..</div>
    <div class="card">..</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.all-results{
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-flex;
    position: relative;
    }
 .wrapper {
    margin-left: 54px;
    width: 100%;
    }
  .card{
    top: 0 !important;
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-left: 16px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
     transition: all 0.2s linear;
    } 
  .card:hover {
      -webkit-transform: translate(0px, -3px);
      transform: translate(0px, -3px);
    }
```

I have to use float too keep my card div beside each other,but I don't know how to transform my card div when i am using float.

Comment: Please expand the code you include in your question so that if we run your code it will actually reproduce the problem.

Comment: @cjl750 I would like to,but this problem only occur in specific version of google chrome, and maybe you can't see the problem,my div with class "card" has to move up because of transform,but it first move to right then goes up

Comment: Change from `all` to `transform` in the transition property: `transition: transform 0.2s linear;` ... and don' forget it in all the prefixed one's

Comment: You also have a typo in your CSS, where there is a stray colon `:` in the rule `.card:{`

Comment: why use of  `:` after `.card:{` ?

Comment: @ehsan It is a typo ... and causing that rule to not work at all

Comment: @tannaz ,   in `.card:hover {`  use `-2px` for  `-webkit-transform` and `-3px` for `transform`.use same values and see result.

Comment: @ehsan That value is for the vertical translation, so won't change anything

Comment: @LGSon .card: this mistake happens here ,i write correct in my real code,tnx

Comment: @LGSon ok I will try what you suggest,I hope it helps my problem,tnx

Comment: @ehsan tnx,but this is a mistake that happens here,i use same value in my real code,i don't know why divs goes right instead of goes up,when i use translate

Comment: @LGSon you mean that if I use transition:transform 0.2s linear; div just goes up and don't goes right first?

Comment: Yes, I mean that. The `all` means to animate all properties and that can be the issue here, as some properties might be interpreted as changed by the browser itself and then you can get unexpected result

Comment: I also posted this as answer, so let me know if it worked or not (and if not I will delete it)

Comment: Since I didn't got a response I deleted my answer